# Backcolor different on different machine

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I copied an entire Solution directory from one machine to another. Both are using the same versions of VS2010 and .net4.5.x

When I look in properties for a control. I see "Transparent" on machineA and "Control" on machineB

How could that happen? Make me worry what else might have got changed...

```
Microsoft Visual Studio 2010
Version 10.0.40219.1 SP1Rel
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.5.50938 SP1Rel

Installed Version: Professional

Microsoft Office Developer Tools   
Microsoft Office Developer Tools

Microsoft Visual C# 2010  
Microsoft Visual C# 2010

Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Team Explorer  
Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Team Explorer

Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2010 
Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2010

Critical Update for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU (KB2938807)   KB2938807
This critical update is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this critical update will be uninstalled automatically.
For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2938807.

Crystal Reports Templates for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010   
Crystal Reports Templates for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010

Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU (KB2529927)   KB2529927
This hotfix is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this hotfix will be uninstalled automatically.
For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2529927.

Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU (KB2542054)   KB2542054
This hotfix is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this hotfix will be uninstalled automatically.
For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2542054.

Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU (KB2548139)   KB2548139
This hotfix is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this hotfix will be uninstalled automatically.
For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2548139.

Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU (KB2549864)   KB2549864
This hotfix is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this hotfix will be uninstalled automatically.
For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2549864.

Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU (KB2635973)   KB2635973
This hotfix is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this hotfix will be uninstalled automatically.
For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2635973.

Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU (KB2890573)   KB2890573
This hotfix is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this hotfix will be uninstalled automatically.
For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2890573.

Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU Service Pack 1 (KB983509)   KB983509
This service pack is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this service pack will be uninstalled automatically.
For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/983509.

Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 SharePoint Developer Tools   10.0.40219
Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 SharePoint Developer Tools

Security Update for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU (KB2644980)   KB2644980
This security update is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this security update will be uninstalled automatically.
For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2644980.

Security Update for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU (KB2645410)   KB2645410
This security update is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this security update will be uninstalled automatically.
```

Comment: Since there is no __real__ transparency in Winforms controls I guess the parent of the Control has color=Control. Is that so?

Comment: @TaW It may not be real - but it is a selectable option. And when copied to machineB a DIFFERENT selectable option has been selected.

Comment: Yes, I understand. I was just asking if it may be caused by an unwanted (and buggy) misinterpretation of what should be displayed..?

Comment: I don't think so. Both display what they have been told to. It's just that the option has changed on machineB

Comment: Is it the same *operating system* on both?

Comment: Isn't control the default? So could it just have reverted form settings to the defaults? Were any other settings changed (if they were not already the defaults)?

Comment: Yes. It have change the backcolor of many controls to default "custom". The can't be correct bevaviour